# Link to Statistics of the app not appearing on Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play

I have 3 apps in my android developer account, 2 free and 1 paid. I cannot find the link to statistics(bellow active install) for my paid app(It's there for other two). What is the problem?

Comment: did you find your problem ?, I have the same situation and it not temporary it is for 5 days till now

Comment: write to support team stating the problem. They resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. If for some application there is no active installs then the statistics button is gone, even if there are for example more than 100 installs

Answer (score 0):

Published application statistics are not shown immediately. It takes around about 24hrs for the stats to get displayed. Atleast it did in my case.